# Can someone help me to fix an error pls-00049?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have created a trigger to my Oracle task  and got some errors and i'm trying to solve but  don't know how. I was searching fix to my error but i didn't find helpful solution
Is someone can help me to do it, please?

So here's my code:

```
   create table sourcetablename_log (
    id  number, 
    operation_date date,
    old_username varchar2(20),
    new_username varchar2(20),
    old_first_name varchar2(20),
    new_first_name varchar2(20),
    old_last_name varchar2(20),
    new_last_name varchar2(20),
    action varchar2(20),
    author varchar2(20)
    );

    create or replace trigger src_log 
    before insert or delete or update on sourcetablename_log
    for each row
    begin
    if inserting then 
    insert into sourcetablename_log(id, operation_date, new_username,  new_firstname, new_lastname)
    values (:new.id, sysdate, :new.username, :new.firstname, :new.lastname);
    elsif updating then 
    insert into sourcetablename_log(id, operation_date, old_username, new_username, old_firstname, new_firstname, old_lastname, new_lastname)
    values (:new.id, sysdate, :old.username, :new.username, :old.firstname, :new.firstname, :old.lastname, :new.lastname);
    elsif deleting then 
    insert into sourcetablename_log(id, operation_date, old_username, new_username, old_firstname, new_firstname, old_lastname, new_lastname)
    values (:new.id, sysdate, :old.username, :new.username, :old.firstname, :new.firstname, :old.lastname, :new.lastname);
    end if;
    end src_log;
```

And here's an error:

```
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
4/27      PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.USERNAME'
4/42      PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.FIRSTNAME'
4/58      PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.LASTNAME'
7/27      PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.USERNAME'
7/42      PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.USERNAME'
7/57      PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.FIRSTNAME'
7/73      PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.FIRSTNAME'
7/89      PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.LASTNAME'
7/104     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.LASTNAME'
10/27     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.USERNAME'
10/42     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.USERNAME'
10/57     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.FIRSTNAME'
10/73     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.FIRSTNAME'
10/89     PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.LASTNAME'
10/104    PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.LASTNAME'
Errors: check compiler log
```

My problem is:

Automate creation of logging table and associated with it triggers A Create a stored procedure that creates a LOGGING table with corresponding columns of OLD values and NEW values, ACTION column, that should be filled in by type of an ACTION and user name (AUTHOR)
Example: You have a table USER of users with next columns:

1. USERNAME VARCHAR
2. FIRST_NAME VARCHAR
3. LAST_NAME VARCHAR

Your procedure should produce a new table with name of “SOURCETABLENAME”_LOG - in this case - USER_LOG with next columns:

1. ID NUMBER [or OPERATION_ID NUMBER]
2. OPERATION_DATE DATE
3. OLD_USERNAME VARCHAR
4. NEW_USERNAME VARCHAR
5. OLD_FIRST_NAME VARCHAR
6. NEW_FIRST_NAME VARCHAR
7. OLD_LAST_NAME VARCHAR
8. NEW_LAST_NAME VARCHAR
9. ACTION VARCHAR
10. AUTHOR VARCHAR**

Comment: I would assume that there is another table `sourcetable` that you haven't shown.  And I would expect that you mean to define the trigger to fire when `sourcetable` is modified to insert data into `sourcetable_log`.  You've defined the trigger on `sourcetable_log` but you're referencing columns like `username` and `lastname` that don't exist in `sourcetable_log`.  I assume they exist in `sourcetable`.

Comment: Are you really sure you meant to have the trigger `on sourcetablename_log`? As it's inserting to that table, should it be on some other table, e.g. `on sourcetablename`?

Comment: i don't have other table. Should i create it?

Comment: "You have a table USER" - so your trigger should be `on user`? (Except `user` is a reserved word...) It sounds like this is supposed to be a procedure that takes the name of an existing table and creates both a log table and trigger, based on the columns in that table. In the example the log table should be called `user_log`. You seem to have missed a few steps from your task. I guess you're currently being taught about dynamic SQL?

Comment: I have created table sourcetablename as user and still got those errors.

Comment: it should be like this:     `create table  sourcetablename(
username varchar2(20),
first_name varchar2(20),
last_name varchar2(20)
);
 create or replace trigger src_log1 
    before insert or delete or update on sourcetablename
    for each row
    begin
    if inserting then 
    insert into sourcetablename_log(id, operation_date, new_username,  new_firstname, new_lastname)
    values (id, sysdate, :new.new_username, :new.new_firstname, :new.new_lastname);`
   '?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If column name is e.g. `new_username`, then you'd use `:new.new_username`, not just `:new.username`.

The same goes for all other columns.

For example:

```
insert into sourcetablename_log(id, operation_date, new_username,  new_firstname, new_lastname)
    values (:new.id, sysdate, :new.new_username, :new.new_firstname, :new.new_lastname);
```

Comment: It seems likely those column names are correct, and the trigger table name is wrong - as it's inserting into the same table the trigger is defined against

Comment: Right, @Alex, didn't notice that. Looks like `ON SOURCETABLENAME_LOG` is wrong, should be some other table.

Comment: so, as i understand i need to create new table or what?

Comment: You are logging changes on "some table" into the SOURCETABLENAME_LOG. Which table is it? It is useless to have a log table and a trigger based on the same log table. Do you not have the SOURCETABLENAME itself?

Comment: oh, ok, i don't have. Thanks.